# Powershell get Folder permissions without inheritance

Tags: powershell, inheritance, active-directory, powershell-2.0, acl

I wondered if there is a simple way to list the permissions of a folder with all of its subfolders but once the rights get inherited from the folder above it should not list the folder because then my list would be too large. I have some code of a working way to check the folder permissions but right now, it also lists the folder with inherited permissions.

```
$User = "Testumgebung\cbruehwiler"
$UserOhneDomain = "cbruehwiler"
$Path = "T:\"
$List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserOhneDomain

$GroupArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $GroupArrayList.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null
}

# Fields we want in list, an array of calculated properties.
$OutputFields = @(
    @{name="Item" ;       expression={$_.Path.split(':',3)[-1]}}
    @{name="Rights" ;     expression={$Right.FileSystemRights}}
    @{name="AccessType" ; expression={$Right.AccessControlType}}
    @{name="From" ;       expression={$User}}
)
$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User) {
            $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
        }
    }
}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        foreach ($GroupArrayItem in $GroupArrayList){
            if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("TESTUMGEBUNG\" + $GroupArrayItem)) {
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
        }
    }
}

$List | Out-File C:\Users\cbruehwiler\Desktop\PermissionCheck.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter it out using the `IsInherited` value of each access.

```
if($Right.IsInherited -eq $false){
    //do stuff
}
```